# remove +/- symbol off the price in Magento 1.9v

Tags: magento

I have tried to find this solution but I can't figure it out.

I'm using an Magento v. 1.9 as my ecommerce platform and entered my products under "simple products" and used custom selection with an associated product. When I go to select a product it look like this `+4.99`.

I want to remove the plus sign next to the amount.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: http://moonravenproductions.com/image/screenshot.jpg]

Need help figuring out how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`

Add following after line 69 approximate.

```
$priceStr = str_replace("+","",$priceStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

for magento 1.9 I've managed to get rid of the +/- signs editing the file

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php
and edited the line number 127:

```
$priceStr = $sign;
```

to look like this:

```
$priceStr = '';
```

To see total price instead of price difference follow this tutorial: [Magento Custom Options – Change the Option to show total price](http://freemagentotips.blogspot.sk/2014/01/magento-custom-options-change-option-to.html)